# purpose of DIR(used with ORGANIZER, ATTENDEE) attribute in iCal?

Tags: icalendar

I added DIR attribute in my ics file for an event with the ORGANIZER property. My code is like

`ORGANIZER;DIR="ldap://example.com:6666/o=ABC%20Industries,c=US???(cn=Jim%20Dolittle)":mailto:jimdo@example.com`

But i don't know where it is actually used or how it will be shown to my invitee.

Answer (score 0):

iCalendar has LOTS of features. Clients that use iCalendar don't need to implement or use all the features. So if it's shown to an invitee is completely dependent on the client which you are using.

Comment: But i just want to know the purpose of it. How it is used( those who implemented DIR)?

Comment: It might be used to identify who someone is in an LDAP directory. Just like the `EMAIL` parameter identifies what a person's email might be. If that doesn't answer your question, you'll have to be a lot more specific.

Comment: I have information about the organiser or attendees in LDAP directory. Now if i give that LDAP url in DIR tag, how it will be shown or where it is shown to my invitee? Or will it be used for any other purposes?

Comment: Again, this depends on the client. The parameter is informational. The specification doesn't say what a client _should_ be doing with it. I imagine most clients don't use it.